# Returning Null Rows From Query

Tags: sql, db2

I was wondering if anyone could assist me with a DB2 query I'm working on?

I'm basically trying to do a left outer join between two tables `DB2Cust` and `NOTIFICATION_REQUE` on `Control Number`.

I want to return all rows in `DB2Cust`, however, in `NOTIFICATION_REQUE` I want to select the max `Notice_DT` and return that record only.

The below query is what I have so far.

It's close but it doesn't return control numbers in `DB2Cust` that don't exist in `NOTIFICATION_REQUE`.

```
SELECT 
    C.CONTROL_NO,
    NR.CONTROL_NBR, 
    COALESCE(C.LNAME,'') AS LNAME, 
    COALESCE(C.FNAME,'') AS FNAME, 
    COALESCE(CAST(NR.NOTICE_DT AS VARCHAR(10)), '') AS NOTICE_DT 
FROM WITC00DS.DB2CUST C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN WITC00DS.NOTIFICATION_REQUE NR 
             ON C.CONTROL_NO = NR.CONTROL_NBR 
      AND C.AGENT_CODE = 'HR' AND C.STW_DATE BETWEEN '01/01/2000' AND '01/17/2014' 
WHERE NR.NOTICE_DT = (SELECT MAX(NOTICE_DT) 
                      FROM WITC00DS.NOTIFICATION_REQUE ZZ 
                      WHERE ZZ.CONTROL_NBR = C.CONTROL_NO)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two choices.  You can move the subquery to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT C.CONTROL_NO, NR.CONTROL_NBR, COALESCE(C.LNAME,'') AS LNAME, COALESCE(C.FNAME,'') AS FNAME,
       COALESCE(CAST(NR.NOTICE_DT AS VARCHAR(10)), '') AS NOTICE_DT 
FROM WITC00DS.DB2CUST C LEFT OUTER JOIN
     WITC00DS.NOTIFICATION_REQUE NR 
     ON C.CONTROL_NO = NR.CONTROL_NBR AND
        C.AGENT_CODE = 'HR' AND
        C.STW_DATE BETWEEN '01/01/2000' AND '01/17/2014'  AND
        NR.NOTICE_DT = (SELECT MAX(NOTICE_DT) 
                        FROM WITC00DS.NOTIFICATION_REQUE ZZ 
                        WHERE ZZ.CONTROL_NBR = C.CONTROL_NO
                       )
```

Or you can explicitly check for `NULL` in the `WHERE clause:

```
SELECT C.CONTROL_NO, NR.CONTROL_NBR, COALESCE(C.LNAME,'') AS LNAME, COALESCE(C.FNAME,'') AS FNAME,
       COALESCE(CAST(NR.NOTICE_DT AS VARCHAR(10)), '') AS NOTICE_DT 
FROM WITC00DS.DB2CUST C LEFT OUTER JOIN
     WITC00DS.NOTIFICATION_REQUE NR 
     ON C.CONTROL_NO = NR.CONTROL_NBR AND
        C.AGENT_CODE = 'HR' AND
        C.STW_DATE BETWEEN '01/01/2000' AND '01/17/2014'  AND
WHERE NR.NOTICE_DT is null or
      NR.NOTICE_DT = (SELECT MAX(NOTICE_DT) 
                      FROM WITC00DS.NOTIFICATION_REQUE ZZ 
                      WHERE ZZ.CONTROL_NBR = C.CONTROL_NO
                     );
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your help ... However, when I try your first solution above I get "An ON clause associated with a JOIN operator or in a MERGE statement is not valid.  SQLSTATE=42972".

Comment: @user2997454 . . . It would seem that DB2 does not support that syntax (although other databases do).  I prefer the second version anyway.